# Using taggit django

Tags: django, django-taggit, django-tagging

I am using the django taggit to add tags to all bids.

My bid model is as follows:

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

How can I remove a particular tag from all bids who have that tag?

I was going to do the following:

Let's say I want to remove the tag "delicious" from all bids with that tag:

```
bids = Bid.objects.filter(tags__name__in=["delicious"])
bids.tags.remove("delicious")
```

Is that the correct way to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, this is the correct way, did you encounter any problems?

Comment: the problem is I am removing the tags from many bids not just one. Does .remove() work for many bids?

Comment: based on the documentation it's working

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this.
In your example, `bids` is a queryset and attribute `tags` is not available on queryset.

You have defined attribute `tags` on class `Bid`, so it is available on any instance of `Bid`. But,it would not be available on the queryset.

For removing tag *delicious* on all the bids in your example:

```
for bid in bids:
    bid.tags.remove("delicious")
```